# js to update dynamic table field with attributes in select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table where the select option has multiple attributes. What i want to do is to get these multiple attributes populated to adjusent cells in the same row next to the select element.The select element is in the first cell in the dynamic row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <td>
            <select name="savings_account_number[]" id="savings_account_number" class="form-control">
                <option value="610005" pro_id="6" available_bal="4500" cap_gl="10101" account_number="610005">610005</option>
                <option value="510006" pro_id="5" available_bal="8900" cap_gl="10102" account_number="510006">510006</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="pro_id[]" id="pro_id"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="available_bal[]" id="pro_id"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="cap_gl[]" id="cap_gl"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="account_number[]" id="account_number"/>
        </td>
    </html>
```

I want this to happen for the onchange activity

Comment: Well you'd only be able to populate those other empty inputs to the right of the selector if you are pulling info from a database or a local file and know how to fill that data in and where. A little bit more clarity in your question would help

Comment: please clarify what you want!

Comment: i want to get the pro_id, cap_gl_ and account_number that are in the option attributes to populate in the input cells that has the id's cap_gl , account_number, and pro_id. This is a dynamic table, and need to happen at the point of changing the  savings_account_number selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If correctly understood, this is a possible solution using jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <select name="savings_account_number[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="610005" pro_id="6" available_bal="4500" cap_gl="10101" account_number="610005">610005</option>
        <option value="510006" pro_id="5" available_bal="8900" cap_gl="10102" account_number="510006">510006</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="pro_id[]" id="pro_id"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="available_bal[]" id="available_bal"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="cap_gl[]" id="cap_gl"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="account_number[]" id="account_number"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <select name="savings_account_number[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="1245" pro_id="5" available_bal="454" cap_gl="3659" account_number="65987">1245</option>
        <option value="6598" pro_id="43" available_bal="3215" cap_gl="64545" account_number="645444">6598</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="pro_id[]" id="pro_id"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="available_bal[]" id="available_bal"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="cap_gl[]" id="cap_gl"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="account_number[]" id="account_number"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table select").change(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var option = select.find("option[value=" + select.val() + "]");
    var tr = select.parents("tr:first");
    if(option.length > 0){
      tr.find("#pro_id").val(option.attr("pro_id"));
      tr.find("#available_bal").val(option.attr("available_bal"));
      tr.find("#cap_gl").val(option.attr("cap_gl"));
      tr.find("#account_number").val(option.attr("account_number"));
    }
    else{
      tr.find("#pro_id").val("");
      tr.find("#available_bal").val("");
      tr.find("#cap_gl").val("");
      tr.find("#account_number").val("");
    }
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Note that I've corrected the second input's `id`, which had the same identifier as the first one.
Also, the select change eventhandler is raised explicetly to load the current value on load.

Comment: Yes it works, but the tr's are dynamic. I only can get this to work in the initial table row. how can i get it work for any dynamic row generated? Thanks

Comment: Just replace the first JS line of code by `$("table select")` and it will work for all existing `tr`s. Notice that the eventhandler only acts over the `tr` in which the changed select lives. Additionally, your table should have an ID or something to prevent the above selector to affect other tables in the page.

Comment: Hi you mean to change "var select = $(this);" to $("table select")?

Comment: No, replace `$("#savings_account_number")` by `$("table select")`

Comment: it does not work still. the next row with same elements does not have this function working. Only the first row has the function working properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've just added another row to the code of my answer. And it works. Please checkt it out and try to understand why. You didn'y post your code, so I cannot guess what you have in front.